# HTTP POST in Android with underscore in URL

Tags: java, android, http

I have seen in other posts that an URL with underscores doesn't work with this code. It's because underscores are not allowed in hostnames:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.my_page.com");
```

But is there any other way to avoid this error or is this not possible in any way?
I have not found a solution yet of this problem in other posts.

Comment: `www.my_page.com` is not a valid FQDN. How did you manage to configure that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

> Hostnames are composed of series of labels concatenated with dots, as
>   are all domain names. For example, "en.wikipedia.org" is a hostname.
>   Each label must be between 1 and 63 characters long,[2] and the entire
>   hostname (including the delimiting dots but not a trailing dot) has a
>   maximum of 253 ASCII characters.[3]
>
> **The Internet standards for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may
>   contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive
>   manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-').** The
>   original specification of hostnames in RFC 952, mandated that labels
>   could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must not end with a
>   hyphen. However, a subsequent specification (RFC 1123) permitted
>   hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation
>   characters, or white space are permitted.
>
> While a hostname may not
>   contain other characters, such as the underscore character (_), other
>   DNS names may contain the underscore.

or from http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html

> Underscores allowed, except in host names
>
> **Host names are not
>   allowed to have underscores in them.** In DNS, host names are the name
>   fields of A or MX records or the data fields of the SOA and NS
>   records. Thus, there are many DNS entries that are not hostnames.

Summary: you cannot use underscores in a host name. You shouldn't want to either.

Answer (score -4):

Did you try replacing the underscore with `&#95;` ?